# One site takes a long time to make a connection, other sites on server fine

Tags: apache-2.2, performance

On a CentOS server with multiple websites, one particular site takes a long time to respond to requests from some geographical areas, but not from other geographical areas. Other sites on the same server are not affected. For instance, if I try to reach the website without a proxy, then the site takes a long time to connect upwards of 10 seconds (confirmed with `wget -p`). As soon as the connection is made, the pages and images download very quickly. If I configure my browser to use a proxy through Amazon, then the site loads very quickly (no connection latency). I see nothing in the error logs that might give a clue.

Note that each site on this server has a different IP address. However, I don't see anything different about the configuration for this site's IP address, sites-enabled file, or anything else that might give a clue as to the origin of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The sites have same class (for ex. from the same /24 ) IP addresses? If the IP's are from different blocks i could imagine a routing problem with one block.

Second guess: the site tries to get the reverse DNS of the connecting IP, and that times out. Or maybe depending on the connecting geographical area does some API call's to different servers (and one server is down/slow)

Comment: Thank you. The sites are in fact on different C blocks. How might I check routing problems for a block? As for the second guess, there is no such logic in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Compare traceroute output from that geo area to a 'good' IP and to a 'bad' IP .Also traceroute output from the server setting the source IP first to the 'good' IP then to 'bad' (-s on linux ). BTW, what are the ping times to the 2 different IP ?